Are there phonological systems proposed for English without the schwa as a phoneme?
The STRUT vowel is clearly a phoneme and it shouldn't be "insulted" by calling it "stressed schwa".
Can the schwa be explained as reduced forms of other phonemes?
EDIT:
if ALL these are examples of "stressed schwa" - it stretches credulity.
https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/lexicalsets/chapter/5-strut-lexical-set/#:~:text=Many%20words%20within%20the%20strut,%2C%20income%2C%20lifeblood%2C%20thermocouple.

Short Phrases
Shut the fuck up!
What* wonderful luck!
Fun in the sun
Some fun summer lovin’.
Percussionists love the drums.
Umbrella weather in London.
The Hungarian ski-jumper tumbled.
A peanut, coconut, and fudge donut.
The skunk stunk up the stump.
An unlovable fussbudget.
Dunk your bun in the mushroom soup.
Ms. McGovern summed one hundred numbers.
Multi-colored scrunch-butt leggings.
The ultimate rum punch.
Lucky son of a gun.


I'm curious, do you actually distinguish STRUT from schwa phonetically? Very few dialects do now.

@Draconis did you mean to say phonemically? Most of them still distinguish it phonetically

@Draconis very few American dialects do, British dialects typically have it more similar to the FOOT vowel (ofc, many British dialects lack the FOOT/STRUT split)

Why do you think it stretches credulity for all those examples to be stressed schwas?

SO MANY examples of sound changes that INCREASED articulatory effort? @Tristan

@SK I don't see how that answers my question

I don't see why that stretches credulity. You could make phrases like that for every vowel in English.

@SK What articulatory effort is increased in what sound changes here? Most of the words in that quote originally had [u] and now have something that is varyingly (depending on dialect) something like [ə ~ ʌ ~ ɐ], all of which are more centralised and thus more neutral vowels. In other words, they require less articulatory effort now than they used to.

Sort of. You have to add an extra level of stress to account for it, though.
Many vowels in English (the "long" vowels) primarily appear in stressed syllables, with schwa taking their place in unstressed syllables. So some linguists analyze schwa as an allophone of all those other vowels when unstressed.
The problem is, there are also exceptional words that have "long" vowels in unstressed syllables, like "finite". If you take vowel reduction as an allophonic process, you have to explain why it doesn't happen here. The usual solution is to introduce a new level of stress, "tertiary" stress: it doesn't act like primary or secondary stress prosodically, and its only effect is to mark unstressed syllables that don't show vowel reduction.
Other linguists say this is overly complicated, and just make schwa its own phoneme instead. The problem with this is that alternations like "photograph"~"photography" can't be explained synchronically any more, and have to be explained diachronically instead.

And even if you add tertiary stress, you still need to account for minimal pairs with primary stress, such as just /dʒʌst/ ‘fair’ vs just /dʒəst/ ‘only’ or butt /bʌt/ vs but /bət/ (the latter only – though commonly – with contrastive stress, normally unstressed).

@JanusBahsJacquet Do people still make that distinction, though? I thought it was only in especially archaic RP at this point.

@JanusBahsJacquet (Though regardless, the question specifically says they're not considering STRUT the same as schwa.)

Well, I certainly still make it, both in BrE and AmE…

@Draconis as a Brit I'd be surprised to hear someone not make that distinction (at least in accents with a FOOT-STRUT split), because this side of the pond schwa is typically closer to FOOT than STRUT

@JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure that's true - all those examples with a schwa shift to STRUT when under prosodic stress

@Draconis I'm in agreement with the other comments that in England merging strut and schwa is more marked than having them separate.

@Tristan I know they do for some people, but not for me. “It’s just not just(ice)” to me is, roughly, [ɪ(ʔ)s ˈdʒəst nɔʔ ˈdʒʌst(ɪs)], with clearly distinct vowels.

@JanusBahsJacquet "it's just not just(ice)" wouldn't have prosodic stress on the first "just", do you mean "it's just not just(ice)" which would?

@Tristan Yes, I meant it with prosodic stress.

interesting, that sounds extremely odd to me, at least in British accents with the FOOT-STRUT split (for American accents, or accents without the FOOT-STRUT split it doesn't sound so strange)

I believe you're conflating two meanings of "schwa": the traditional "unstressed neutral vowel of English" and "a phoneme in the middle of the vowel spectrum, or the turned-e symbol for that phoneme".
The first meaning is specific to the "unmerged" analysis of English, where STRUT and commA are taken to be distinct phonemes. If you're using that analysis, then "schwa" cannot be stressed.
But it is also possible to analyse English vowels with a system combining the STRUT and commA lexical sets. It makes no difference whether you choose to write this vowel as "/ʌ/" or "/ə/" or "/ɐ/"; you're referring to the same phoneme in any case. If you denote it with /ə/, you might call the phoneme "schwa", because that's the name for the letter ə, and it's also one of the phonemes that were merged into this new phoneme.
If you do choose to call this merged phoneme "schwa", that does not automatically make it unstressed by default. Like other English vowels, it can be stressed or unstressed, and in most one-syllable words, it will be stressed by default. It doesn't require any more effort - or any more explanation - than stress on any other vowel.

As in many matters in linguistics - there are only opinions as to whether the schwa is an independent phoneme or not.  Here is one - including what linguists call schwa in /ɪ/
Fowler wasn't a linguist, but in his Dictionary of Modern English Usage (second edition) - he recognizes what linguists call the wedge vowel as a regular vowel (as in "ruck") and what linguists call schwa not worth recognizing as a thing.

KEY TO PRONUNCIATION
VOWELS
ā ē ī ō ū ōō (mate, mete, mite, mote, mute, moot)
ă ĕ ĭ ŏ ŭ ŏŏ (rack, reck, rick, rock, ruck, rook)
(The light vague er sound often given to short vowels in unstressed syllables, and the i sound often given to unstressed e, are not separately distinguished.)
ār̄ ēr̄ īr̄ ōr̄ ūr̄ (mare, mere, mire, more, mure)
ar er or (part, pert, port)
ah aw oi oor ow owr (bah, bawl, boil, boor, brow, bower)


what do you mean when you say "what linguists call schwa in /I/"? I have never heard this term before. Do you mean /ɪ/ (sometimes called a schwi in unstressed syllables)?

schwi is also occasionally transcribed with ɨ, but typically only in fairly narrow phonetic transcription, phonemic and broader phonetic transcriptions pretty universally transcribe it identically to the KIT vowel (i.e. /ɪ/ may sometimes be transcribed [ɨ] in unstressed syllables)

the nerdy precisionism on Stack Exchange is something I can never get used to. I typed /I/ but apparently it is not the same as /ɪ/ . I wouldn't have noticed the difference in a million years.  i have corrected it now.

That was not my issue. I have also never heard of a "schwa in /ɪ/". I have heard of schwa, and I have heard of /ɪ/, but not a "schwa in /ɪ/"

no, that doesn't clear things up at all. Are you trying to gesture at the weak vowel merger (where some dialects of English have merged /ə/ with unstressed /ɪ/)?

@Tristan I think the intended meaning is “subsuming under /ɪ/ the vowel that linguists call schwa”. But I don’t really understand Fowler’s phrasing, to be honest: I don’t know what sounds he’s trying to describe as “the light vague er sound” and “the i sound often given to unstressed e” – eminently vague descriptions. And of course what he’s describing is a phonetic respelling system for a dictionary, not a phonemic analysis of English, so it’s not really relevant to the question asked at all.

@JanusBahsJacquet being British, Fowler is describing a non-rhotic variety, so “the light vague er sound” is undoubtedly [ə] (typically spelt "er" in phonetic spellings by British laypeople); “the i sound often given to unstressed e” then is undoubtedly [ᵻ~ɪ̈~ɨ~ɪ] (depending on transcription convention). I think he's just saying that his transcription doesn't distinguish them (from full unreduced vowels), and not actually making any phonetic (let alone phonemic) claims. I'd have to check a more up-to-date edition to be more certain though

Regardless, I don't think anyone includes all schwas under /ɪ/, or all /ɪ/ under schwas. The closest people come are acknowledging the weak vowel merger (i.e. schwa and /ɪ/ are merged in unstressed syllables) or giving schwa as a mere unstressed allophone of /ʌ/. Ofc both those mergers are only valid in dialects with their respective mergers

While many people may use an uppercase letter i even though that's not the official IPA character, /I/ looks like an L in this font so it's especially confusing.
